# svnserve accepts only local connection

Tags: linux, windows, debian, svnserve

I've installed svnserve in linux box konrad. On konrad I can checkout from svn:

```
steve@konrad:~$ svn co svn://konrad
A    konrad/build.xml
```

On my local Windows pc i can ping konrad, but checkout doesn work:

```
C:\Projects>svn co svn://konrad
svn: E730061: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://konrad'
svn: E730061: Can't connect to host 'konrad': Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.
```

My linux firewall is disabled:

```
konrad# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

and windows firewall is also off (I can't send screen shot here, so believe me).
How can I fix that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `svnserve` with a `--listen-host` of `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @stiv: Please indicate this answer is correct by clicking the little 'tick' to the left of my answer.